# Let $D= \{ (x,y)∈\mathbb{R}^2:|x|+|y|≤1 \}$ and $f:D \to \mathbb{R}$ be a non-constant continuous function. Which of the following is true?

Tags: calculus

The options are:

1. The range of $f$ is unbounded
2. The range of $f$ is a union of open intervals
3. The range of $f$ is a closed interval
4. The range of $f$ is a union of at least two disjoint closed intervals

The only thing I have been able to figure out is the region enclosed by the set $D$. I would like to know the correct answer with the necessary explanation.

Comment: “The only thing… enclosed by the set $D$”, that's hard to understand. What have you tried explicitly? See [How to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959).

Comment: @Saad The region representing the domain of the function *f*, i.e., the set D. I'm afraid that may not have anything to do with the solution.

Comment: So all you have tried so far is to aknowledge that $f$ is defined on $D$, which is clearly written in the problem description itself?

Comment: @Saad Yes. My knowledge of calculus is restricted to elementary calculus, so I have no idea about proceeding with a solution whatsoever.

Comment: Pick a simple example: for example, $f(x, y) = x+y$.  That's continuous.  What qualities does it possess?

Comment: @BrianTung Mmm that the limit at every point in its domain is equal to the function value?

Comment: No.  Go through the four options.  Which of those, if any, describe $f(x, y) = x+y$?  If you aren't willing to go through that effort, this question should be closed.  If you aren't able to go through that process, you probably need to read through whatever course materials you're supposed to until you can.

Comment: @BrianTung My bad. I guess it has an unbounded range?

Comment: Over the domain $D$?

Comment: @BrianTung I think the function *f* you presented as *f(x,y)=x+y* has an unbounded range. Is that correct?

Comment: Over $\mathbb{R}^2$ it does.  I repeat: What about over the domain $D$, which $f$ is restricted to?

Comment: @BrianTung Understood. It has a closed interval as a range, [-2,2]

Comment: Good!  Now which of your four options does that fit?

Comment: @BrianTung Option 3, thanks for helping out. I just learnt that compactness, connectedness of the domain in a continuous function guarantee the same properties for the range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since domain of continuous function $f$ is compact and connected, therefore, its image is also compact and connected. Hence, third is the correct option.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the terms "compact" and "connected"(I guess they have something to do with analysis?)

Comment: Yeah, that has something to do with analysis. Your question itself is from real analysis.

Comment: OP: You may need to do another review of terminology and background.

Comment: You can read about these terms on Wikipedia.

Comment: @BrianTung Would an introductory course in analysis suffice to answer such a question?

Comment: @Martund I reviewed the terms on Wikipedia. Does compactness and connectedness of the domain necessitate the same properties for the range?

Comment: @Manan, Yes, that happens if the function is continuous.

Comment: OP: If you are not already studying real analysis, this question may be a little beyond you until you familiarize yourself with its basic concepts.

Comment: @BrianTung Sure, I'll be studying analysis right after I go through multivariable calculus.

Comment: @Manan . Multi-variate calculus is part of analysis. Analysis  has been described as a sprawling octopus.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet I meant the MIT 18.02 sort of multivariable calculus, where formal proofs of theorems are usually avoided. Am I right in assuming that a working knowledge of multivariate calculus and linear algebra is sufficient to begin with rigorous, proof-based analysis?

Comment: @Manan . I would think so.............